# Using a spinner in combination with tab strip for navigation

Tags: android, tabs, navigation, android-actionbar, spinner

How do Google apps, like Google Play Music for example, combine both the Spinner in the action bar with below a fixed tab strip?

[image]

Does it use setNavigationMode(NAVIGATION_MODE_LIST), in combination with a ViewPager with a custom tab strip for navigation? Or otherwise NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS with a custom spinner ActionView in the action bar? Or another option?